# remove GWT textbox shadow effect

Tags: gwt

when we create a textbox in GWT ,it always have a shadow effect(3D effect), borders are not sleek

i search for it but couldn't find a way to remove the default shadow effect from the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on gwt designer, you can define the individual css styles for each widget your use. Just put in the style tag of your widget:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom CSS class for this visual effect, rather than placing the same styles everywhere, so that it will be easier to apply and maintain.

```
input.noShadows {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Then just apply the *noShadows* class to the elements where needed. Or, give *.noShadows input* and just put the class on the form parent container.